# Shipping method save config button doesn't work

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

When I hit in Shipping method configuration "Save Config" button, it does nothing. Other save buttons are working fine.

I can't save shipping method changes now. What I have to do?

Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: add some code #for the button.

Comment: In which location?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: There are many similar question here. Hope stackoverflow will create a separate section about magento to answer all such type questions.